# How can I benchmark or audit an embedded kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, audit, benchmark

Is there a reliable or industry standard way to benchmark or audit embedded kernel performance?

The target of the audit is to determine the time that the kernel spends in certain critical section, particularly interrupt handlers and blocking syscalls as well as recording context switches and io use. Certain userspace threads could be re-prioritized or rescheduled in order to even the load in the context of a soft real-time embedded linux system.

What I have been doing is inserting some spare peripheral IO toggling into strategic syscalls and interrupts to track a small subset of kernel activity with an oscilloscope and minimal impact. This is effective for seeing how long a particular system call takes on average, but does not give much rich information.

For context you can assume a Linux 2.6 kernel and with RT-PREEMPT and Xenomai